# Matlab Axislabel reaches partly in image

Tags: matlab, colorbar

the second scale of my colorbar reaches partly in the image, is there a quick way to fix that?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c=colobar;
pos=get(c,'Position');
set(c,'Position',pos+[0.05 0 0 0])
```

Get the colorbar position, add a bit offset to the `x`.